# How to set a property that depends on the properties of the current object as well as other objects under the same array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I want to declare a function that only need a param, this param type is an array object, each object has `name`,`options` proptery, and optional `all` proptery.

```
type Item = {
  name: string;
  all?: boolean;
  options: <Fields>(fields: Fields) => any[]
}

declare function useLink(items: Item[]): any
```

Then I need restrict the type of `fields`, this `Fields` will get all objects each `name`'s value(Exclude itself), and it value depends on `all` proptery, if `all` is not set or `false`, it will be `string[]`, else it is `string`.

```
useLink(
  [
    {
      name: 'a', all: true,
      options(fields: Fields) { // Fields type is { b: string, c: string, d: string } (Exclude a: string[])
        return [] as any[]
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'b',
      options(fields: Fields) { // Fields type is { a: string[], c: string, d: string } (Exclude b: string)
        return [] as any[]
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'c',
      all: false,
      options(fields: Fields) { // Fields type is { a: string[], b: string, d: string } (Exclude c: string)
        return [] as any[]
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'd', options(fields: Fields) { // Fields type is { a: string[], b: string, c: string } (Exclude d: string)
        return [] as any[]
      }
    }
    // ... more object
  ]
)
```

Now, After trying, the following results are obtained

```
type LinkFields<All extends boolean, Name = string> = {
  name: Name;
  all?: All;
  [x: string]: any
}
/**
 * Example
 * WithOptions<[
    { name: 'a', all: true },
    { name: 'b' },
    { name: 'c', all: false },
    { name: 'd' }
    // ... more object
  ]>
  ->
  [
    {options: (fields: {b: string, c: string, d: string}) => any[] },
    {options: (fields: {a: string[], c: string, d: string}) => any[] },
    {options: (fields: {a: string[], b: string, d: string}) => any[] },
    {options: (fields: {a: string[], b: string, c: string}) => any[] },
    // ... more object
  ]
 */
type WithOptions<T extends readonly any[], Fields = ArrayToObject<T>, R extends any[] = []> =
  T extends [] ? R : T extends [infer H, ...infer Rest] ? H extends { name: string } ? WithOptions<Rest, Fields, [...R, { options: (fields: Omit<Fields, H['name']>) => any[] }]> : never : R

/** To get Tuple not Array */
type TupleParams<T = any> = readonly T[] | readonly [T]

type GetFieldValue<A> = A extends LinkFields<infer T> ? boolean extends T ? string : false extends T ? string : string[] : never;

/**
 * Example
 * ArrayToObject<[
    { name: 'a', all: true },
    { name: 'b' },
    { name: 'c', all: false },
    { name: 'd' }
    // ... more object
  ]>
  ->
  {a: string[], b: string, c: string, d: string}
 */
type ArrayToObject<Arr extends TupleParams<LinkFields<any, any>> = []> = {
  [K in Arr[number]['name']]: GetFieldValue<Extract<Arr[number], { name: K }>>
}

declare function useLink<T extends TupleParams<LinkFields<All, Name>>, Name extends string, All extends boolean>
  (items: T, i?: WithOptions<T>): ArrayToObject<T>

// I only get this effect that i must use two array.
const a = useLink(
  [
    { name: 'a', all: true },
    {
      name: 'b',
    },
    {
      name: 'c',
      all: false
    }
    // ... more object
  ],
  [
    {
      options(fields) { // current fields type is { b: string, c: string }
        return [{ id: '', name: '' }].filter(item => fields.b)
      }
    },
    {
      options(fields) { // current fields type is { a: string[], c: string }
        return [{ id: '', name: '' }].filter(item => fields.a.includes(item.id))
      }
    },
    {
      options(fields){ // current fields type is { a: string[], b: string }
        return [{ id: '', name: '' }].filter(item => fields.b === item.id)
      }
    }
    // ... more object
  ]
)
```

But actually I want the following effect.

```
// I actually want the following effect that just need an array.
const b = useLink(
  [
    {
      name: 'a', all: true,
      options(fields) { // current fields type is { b: string, c: string }
        return [{ id: '', name: '' }].filter(item => fields.b)
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'b',
      options(fields) { // current fields type is { a: string[], c: string }
        return [{ id: '', name: '' }].filter(item => fields.a.includes(item.id))
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'c',
      all: false,
      options(fields) { // current fields type is { a: string[], b: string }
        return [{ id: '', name: '' }].filter(item => fields.b === item.id)
      }
    }
    // ... more object
  ],
)
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgOwNYDE4QDYBMDOAeAQQwyggA9gIFcoAjAe3owgEMEAaKAORYFtoAvFBzAATogDmAPihCA3gCgoUBHwgAubmoDcSqC2IB+TUQy7lAbTKaR4hBIC6mtiAUBfBQHoAVN6XeoAFEyPjBmfygAdThgAAsAeTBgOHoEfAs9ZTkVNU0AchY8zgMMTTEAV2g3dkyobNV+fNo8qGra+tyoPIBjIv1iTQAzAxwqmuUsnMaurBaPCahPTygAOjWoXnpRaHpaACsIbuA9Byk9AFozy3b6JJS0zQAKQfRsHE05WhsxSU5u77sEk4WABkjcAEpZDIXBYHK1xhM5Ldkql3lBnq9cB8WKD7LC-rigVAQcIfvYIVD9AgQLD4Tc7qini9MFi6jjSYD8XRCcDCRSBNDqbS2gskQyHujmW9sYSuV8Ob8oP8FeTIQKqTS4SKJktVutNtsoLsDkcTv5PApQJAojEEuL8AAVUgUKg0bYsLCpDAgDVctAsnCyKAEUSiFggB30eL7Q7APAOqScABKzso1EDMLhQlhMgEeid5DTNFphigKc0BZd6agFkQgwgoigAAlOGsVnWG2WICI4aWm6nXYGOtNbJJWlBS9E4okUWk8Enu8BOP63pwLG2k5xssj7miMQHNPFeDE8CvcJwmxY8g0IHlTmrBZrWqcoJoEBAAG6dzRJhReXxQJGUASBAwCAeUYTQAg9BgSGYY+t4FpWtADoQcwAAKLBhrwjpBi4uZQO6noIN6gG0gAPoRrDEaRFgOg4f7IVAADioFngAagYlSEARBADtW8DIGe+Ado2CYTnQjDMGw-E0E6pajvYr5QMMGCjLJgbySqEjKYpEi0m+n4Nro-5+FAATBKE4TmcGobhpG0YmnGGSilMGhdIUxQDFAFRjO0blNHMCKTDe+S9F5pQqSMfmuaFMxzLUupthsWw7DGprKKcFxXGysoOJw8p6QS2m8tp8yIZa4DQHB9lRulcZwRp4GQZh2H4IJqCYvgLjFNSUgETmQaKJYADSUCILZogWAg5S8LQDYOFeN53k4LFsZinEYNxwRiCwRyEKG02zfNoj5XUAVQGNbj9e4f5YIcGBYdAgzlAgRz3FA5SjB18ZNahLVYXw7WIJ1AaEMQnA8Pw-WQ2oTVFcGxBNQwTCsAgOWPDEEA4RWnBwMYNrTva8ZSOCJh2RGdVOSTf66gAkkaJE+iBYFxHAgYQIM9ZHD5sQsGBcAbF9YFfdAwAAO70PoFMrAo3SomBLBBqLHWPHoLmIhdBR9CUZSiJUdKirUyhxXkzTBYbiLG1r4XW7rUVqRAtTzDqyzJQaaVOScCIa1k1s7qi+5vJC2S6t05ShlQYFSjQTHs+dhVkkSyp6a01vKNswARwgNbZHAJJ5H0ptzA4KwvBglCiJjlC8JSMc4CstDgtbLvKNqfsLMoAdpEHuAh4syzh5HCDR11PlVeNQ76HlxWp63neZ9nufjQXRedIXz5l3AFcNtX2N111KwsO2b1bfdOB77w7ZYOCzed2nCzt3U-v2r3ODgqHg8R9sI8qWPcdT3ZHpOUhIH73yolnUQOcLB51XpwYum9y6V0vgfAMjdZACCEFjK++c76d3nvPJK+pUpGnqmaZuXhlgMz2lnEoPpxZsFZrEZ6TAMD0HFmOTm3MmH8ygHsYWKgIAQCwFSaW8FZbyzSGBWgytvogzVtcI299TaeX6JFXyFsu6v3rv3MO38o5-wDOPa08dsiJ0BLPJOYD76LygcvfO+Q17TA3m4UuSDd7YNQW8RueDH7OwtsNTuptzYv1nBfHR509HD1HkYgB50gFJy5CnKx88Fi2OgbAxx8D14ly3jvKunj1T1yPifboZ9uyX2vrfFu-j2jW1Nrbe+9tVKjE0UabRXVdFf2iYYt4xjoCmOntpEB2lrEL1AkvGBK8sla1ye4gpNcvG4HQZgrBNcqk1L8QsIhKwUqGmNLGb2ChwRAA)
I actually just want to need to input one array instead of two, but I can't.
Is it possible to get the above effect, thank you for any help and hints.

Comment: What if there are 3 objects in the array ? Do you want `useLink` with one array or with two arrays like it is in the second example?

Comment: I added the problem description, I actually just want to need to input one array instead of two, but I can't. @captain-yossarian from Ukraine

Comment: Could you please provide more objects into array argument with `all: true` and `all: false`. And put a comments what you expect in different places

Comment: I have redescribed my problem. Could someone please help me? Thank you very much! Sorry, i get this tips "You must have 50 reputation to comment" that i cannot create a new comment?

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to do in a way you expect